# mmap from file in loop

Tags: c, linux, overflow, mmap

Im trying to work with mmap reading from file in loop,
Im have file contains info about 3 parts, first part is size of 3*sizeof(double),
second one also in the size of 3*sizeof(double), and the third with size of sizeof(double). At the first part of the file I have HEADER with size of 32768 bytes. The file organised:

HEADER||Part(1),Part(1)....Part(1)||Part(2),Part(2)....Part(2)||Part(3),Part(3)....Part(3)|

Each part I have 100 times.
I want to work each time with 30 parts (10 parts from each part).

I have tried this code:

```
void readingFile(FILE *file, double *a, double *b, double *c, int start, int end, int chunksz, long total)
{
    int i = 0;
    int size = end - start + 1;
    int fd;
    fd = fileno(file);
    off_t fullsize = lseek(fd,SEEK_CUR,SEEK_END); //getting the file size
    fullsize-=1;//the lseek gives one more byte, its ok!
    unsigned long summ = (unsigned long)(start-1)*chunksz; //chunk is 56
    summ+=(unsigned long)HEADER_SIZE;//offset the header size
    unsigned long paramm=(unsigned long)((unsigned long)summ/(unsigned long)(sysconf(_SC_PAGE_SIZE)));
    unsigned long param = floor(paramm);
    void *buf=NULL;
    buf =mmap(NULL,fullsize , PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE , fd, param*sysconf(_SC_PAGE_SIZE));
    if(buf==MAP_FAILED)
    {
        printf("we have an error\n");
    }
    unsigned long gapp = (sysconf(_SC_PAGE_SIZE))*param;
    unsigned long gap =summ-gapp;
    buf+=gap;
    memcpy(a,buf,3*sizeof(double)*size);
    buf+=(unsigned long)((long)total-(start-1))*3*sizeof(double);
    buf+=((start-1)*3*sizeof(double));
    memcpy(b,buf,3*sizeof(double)*size);
    buf+=(unsigned long)((long)total-(start-1))*3*sizeof(double);
    buf+=((start-1)*sizeof(double));
    memcpy(c,buf,sizeof(double)*size);
    munmap(buf, fullsize);
    return;
}
```

Somewhere in the way I have Overflow and the program crashing!
Each time the function being called, A new memory is allotted properly to a,b,c.
What is worng here?
The process crashed at iteration number 14 in line:

```
memcpy(c,buf,sizeof(double)*size);
```

Thanks!

Comment: "Somewhere in the way I have Overflow". Use a debugger to find out that "somewhere" exactly.

Comment: If you're getting a file descriptor, [you can use `fstat()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/fstat.html) to get the file size instead of `lseek()`.  Using `lseek()` on the file already opened with a `FILE *` might break things if the `FILE *` data expects the file offset to be where it left it.  You're also mapping a number of bytes equal to the full size of the file - **but from a non-zero offset**.  And if your call to `mmap()` fails, you have to do something other than print out an error and then continue running like nothing happened.

Comment: The file is open, and the Error is not duo to mmap call.

Comment: @kaylum I cant use a debugger. Andrew Henle  The file is open, and the Error is not duo to mmap call.

Comment: Why can't you use a debugger? Anyway, there are other ways to debug. How about `printf`? How about removing all the code and gradually adding a little bit back in each time? You've managed to pack a lot of complexity into a relatively small number of lines of code. It would benefit you to add verification and debugging code (especially to verify all your offset calculations).

Comment: regarding this line:  ` off_t fullsize = lseek(fd,SEEK_CUR,SEEK_END); //getting the file size`   is not correct.   it should be: ` off_t fullsize = lseek( fd, 0, SEEK_END ); //getting the file size`.   Also, lseek() can fail, at which time is returns: `(off_t)-1`  so the returned value must be checked to assure the operation was successful

Comment: @kaylum I debugged it, It fail in the memcpy in iteration number 14. here: memcpy(c,buf,sizeof(double)*size);

Comment: regarding this line: `fullsize-=1;//the lseek gives one more byte, its ok!`  the function: `lseek()` returns an offset, an offset starts with 0 for the first byte in the file. so the returned value should not be modified, unless ADD 1 to get total number of bytes in the file.

Comment: regarding these lines: `unsigned long paramm=(unsigned long)((unsigned long)summ/(unsigned long)(sysconf(_SC_PAGE_SIZE)));
    unsigned long param = floor(paramm);`.   the variable `paramm` is a type of integer, so the function: `floor()` is 1) not appropriate as it expects a `double` parameter and returns a `double`.  To calculate the actual number of pages needed, use something similar to: `double paramm = ((double)(summ+sysconf(_SC_PAGE_SIZE)-1) / sysconf(_SC_PAGE_SIZE);`

Comment: @user3629249 You are right about the floor function, But it doesnt really matter, because there gap that calculated is good for the offset.

Comment: Are you sure you allocated enought space in c to contains the newly created mmap ?

Comment: regarding these three lines: `  unsigned long gapp = (sysconf(_SC_PAGE_SIZE))*param;
    unsigned long gap =summ-gapp;
    buf+=gap;`   1) the variable: `gapp` will be a large (total allocation) value.  2) summ-gapp will be a negative value  3) buf+=gap will set buf to be a smaller value. 4) buf contains a value returned from `mmap()` and will be needed later for the call to: `munmap()`

Comment: regarding this line: `buf =mmap(NULL,fullsize , PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE , fd, param*sysconf(_SC_PAGE_SIZE));`,  this is allocating memory that is the same size as the file, then use the (non-existent) area past the end of the actual file..  suggest changing the `offset` parameter to 0

Comment: any/all changes to the pointer `buf` will be a major problem when calling `munmap()`  strongly suggest creating a new char pointer and perform all calculations using that new pointer.  Then the pointer in `buf` will still be correct when calling `munmap()`.   Since the layout of the file is known. strongly suggest creating a `struct` that overlays the file contents and making all access to the data in the file via that `struct`

Comment: @user3629249 Damn!! I think you are right!!! I will try this!! Thanks!!

Comment: @user3629249 I have tried to work with another void * pointer, and not changing the buf pointer, And it still crash at the same point. What do you think?

Comment: OP  there are a lot of suggested fixes for the posted code.   Perhaps you could post additional text with the latest code.  Other wise, 1) your refering to code that we cannot see, 2) we do not know exactly where the code crashed.  3) your discussing another `void*`.  I'm reasonably sure that nothing in the comments said to create a `void*`.   Note: There was some discussion about creating a struct that overlayed the whole file format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know that answering a question with source code is not familiar. But i try to expaint what a usefull thing is the mmap.
Basically mmap use the kernel capabilities to load (and write back from) the file content into a memory region. so we don't need to frequently call read/seek that can make your application more effective.
In other hand it is a confortable solution to access your data directly, just see the code:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

struct mapping
{
        void* start_addr;
        size_t length;
        int fd;
};

struct mapping* map_file(const char* file)
{
        struct mapping* ret = malloc(sizeof(struct mapping));
        if(NULL == ret)
        {
                printf("Can't allocate memory for struct mapping.\n");
                return NULL;
        }

        ret->fd = open(file, O_RDONLY);
        if(0 > ret->fd)
        {
                perror("can't open specified file.");
                free(ret);
                return NULL;
        }

        struct stat fs;
        if(0 != fstat(ret->fd, &fs))
        {
                perror("can't specify file size.");
                close(ret->fd);
                free(ret);
                return NULL;
        }

        ret->length = fs.st_size;

        //offset means offset in file
        ret->start_addr = mmap(NULL, ret->length, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, ret->fd, 0);
        if(MAP_FAILED == ret->start_addr)
        {
                perror("Mapping file failed.");
                close(ret->fd);
                free(ret);
                return NULL;
        }

        return ret;
}

//returns zero on success and free the `struct mapping` data
int unmap_file(struct mapping* mmf)
{
        //note that now we use read only mapping
        //if you want to write this memory pages
        //before detach maybe you have to call:
        //msync(mmf->start_addr, mmf->length, MS_SYNC);
        // avoid data loss (write all dirty page into file).

        if(NULL != mmf->start_addr)
        {
                if(0 != munmap(mmf->start_addr, mmf->length))
                {
                        perror("Can't munmap file.");
                        return 1;
                }
        }

        mmf->start_addr = NULL;
        if(-1 != mmf->fd)
        {
                if(0 != close(mmf->fd))
                {
                        perror("can't close file descriptor.");
                        return 2;
                }
        }

        free(mmf);

        return 0;
}

// for test#define  MAGIC_START_INDEX 0
#define  MAGIC_START_INDEX 32768

int main(int arg_length, char** args)
{
        if(arg_length < 2)
        {
                printf("No input file specified.\n");
                exit(1);
        }

        int i = 0;
        //first argument is the name of program
        while(++i < arg_length)
        {
                struct mapping* mmf = map_file(args[i]);
                if(NULL == mmf)
                {
                        printf("can't use %s for input file\n", args[i]);
                        continue;
                }

                if(mmf->length >  MAGIC_START_INDEX)
                {
                        //upper base
                        int max_index = (mmf->length - MAGIC_START_INDEX) / sizeof(double);

                        //an offset alias for start memory address
                        double* data = ((double*)(mmf->start_addr + MAGIC_START_INDEX));

                        int ni = 0;
                        while(ni+2 < max_index)
                        {
                                printf("num0: %f, num1: %f, num2: %f\n", data[ni], data[ni+1], data[ni+2]);
                                ni += 3;
                        }
                }
                else
                {
                        printf("File: %s has no valuable data.", args[i]);
                }

                unmap_file(mmf);
        }
}
```

In the main, you see, we can use directly memory addresses instead of repeat read operation. This is a sample code what i copied (mapping related data stored in structure and related functions take care about creating/releace file mapping). That reading can be more lazy, just open the file, read the size (fstat) if i has valuable data, use mmap's offset parameter to skip the header section in the file:

```
double[] data = (double*)(mmap(NULL, file_length, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, fd, MAGIC_START_INDEX)); //TODO check null.
```

and you get "an instant" access to the data.